# Can I force DecisionTreeClassifier to use integer conditions when the variable is integer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, visualization, decision-trees

I'm trying to visualize a decision tree in python for the purpose of explainability. I noticed that a condition like "NumGoals >= 1.23" could be quite vague for the user and I would much rather to see something like this: "NumGoals > 1".

So, I tried to switch the normalization off, and I even suspected that it might be a side effect the input matrix's `dtype`.

This is a simple code to reproduce the results.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(np.array(iris.data, dtype=int), iris.target)
plot_tree(clf)
plt.show()
```

So, is it even possible to tell the tree to treat integers as integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for visualization you could use the `precision` parameter of `plot_tree()`:

> precision: int, optional (default=3)
>
> Number of digits of precision for floating point in the values of impurity, threshold and value attributes of each node.

(see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html))

However, since it also applies `precision` to impurity you might want to turn that off. Here is an example:

`tree.plot_tree(clf)` gives
[image]

`tree.plot_tree(clf, precision=0, impurity=false)` gives
[image: tree.plot_tree(grid_search.best_estimator_)]

(If gini importance was shown, all gini values would be 0 here)

Since it uses $\leq$ and all split thresholds are between the closest $X$ values the split criteria should still be correct. Even if your tree does not use integers. But I'd always double check and compare both plots.

Answer (score 0):

You're right to switch off the normalization. The only way I can think of to force the tree to use integers as integers is to perform one-hot encoding on your features. That will force the tree to see integers as categorical values instead of continuous.