# DecisionTreeClassifier Integer Conditions, Integer Outcome Variable

Tags: decision-trees

Vague condition: "NumGoals >= 1.23"

Preferred condition: "NumGoals > 1".

Switched normalization off.

Code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(np.array(iris.data, dtype=int), iris.target)
plot_tree(clf)
plt.show()
```

Possible to treat integers as integers?

Comment: Can you describe your issue in full sentences please? Does it mean you would like to use integers as split values?

Comment: you could just round the results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I force DecisionTreeClassifier to use integer conditions when the variable is integer?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64383/can-i-force-decisiontreeclassifier-to-use-integer-conditions-when-the-variable-i)